# How to initiate iOS software updates remotely on managed devices?

Tags: ios, software-update, server.app, open-directory, profile-manager

I am trying to setup the so called "Profile Manager" in Apple's Server to manage a number of iOS devices for the family. The main purpose is for me to be able to (1) remotely restart the devices and (2) initiate software updates, if that's possible.

So far I was able to add devices to the "Profile Manager" and view settings for each device. I can configure different general settings, most of which I do not really care about (such as AirPrint, Mail, etc). I also know that the device still needs an iOS Software Update to get to the latest iOS version/

Unfortunately, I can not find a way to start this update remotely. I did come across the "About" page in the web view of the "Profile Manager", which has a section on: "OS, Built-In App, System Data File, and Security Updates", but that simply says "No Updates Available." When I check inside the iOS device under "Software Update", I see "iOS 10.1", though.

[image: Profile Manager says No Updates Available]

Am I missing a certain setup step to get this working or are remote iOS updates just not possible?

Additional info that may be relevant:

- I have enabled Signed configuration profiles, but the certificate is local
- Everything is happening on the local network only, no public domain is involved
- I did not enable any of the "Deployment Programs"

Answer (score 1):

Forcing iOS Updates to devices using Profile Manager is only possible if the devices are in the "supervised" state and the iOS version is out of date to begin with.

Device supervision (the highest level of device management, enables MUCH MORE control over devices) is only possible by:

1. Enrolling in Apple's DEP program (really only practical for device administrators that order a lot of phones for the company)
2. Configuring the device through Apple's free OS X App: Configurator 2

Conf2 will enroll the device in MDM and enable "supervision" on the devices.

http://krypted.com/iphone/enable-device-supervision-on-ios-devices-using-apple-configurator-2/